# In Orchard CMS, how do I display all of a certain ContentType on the front-end as a bulleted list?

Tags: orchardcms

Example:

1. Create a new Product ContentType that has Name ContentField.
2. Create ten new ContentItems that are instances of the Product ContentType.
3. Display the Name of those new ProductContentItems in, say, bulleted list.

This seems like it ought to be trivial but it isn't, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a projection that finds all content items of type Product. Create a custom display using the list type and give the item display type as BulletList. Then add to your themes placement file something like:

```
<Match ContentType="Product">
    <Match DisplayType="BulletList">
        <!-- Hide all parts and fields except Name field -->
        <Place Parts_Title="-" /> <!-- etc. -->
        <Place Fields_Input="Content:1" /> <!-- Don't hide your name field -->
    </Match>
</Match>
```

Add styles etc. as needs be